# Resizing image to memory stream provides wrong FinalHeight and FinalWidth

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I am trying to resize an image using the FitMode.Max parameter, and i need to save the new image dimensions since i am saving the image in my database.

```
 public ImageResizeResponse Resize(Stream stream, int maxHeight = 1024, int maxWidth = 1024)
    {

        var response = new ImageResizeResponse();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            var job = new ImageJob(stream, ms, new Instructions
            {
                Mode = FitMode.Max,
                Scale = ScaleMode.Both,
                JpegQuality = 80,
                OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Jpeg,
                Cache = ServerCacheMode.No,
                Height = maxHeight,
                Width = maxWidth
            });

            job.Build();

            response.FileContent = ms.ToArray();
            response.FinalHeight = job.FinalHeight.GetValueOrDefault();
            response.FinalWidth = job.FinalWidth.GetValueOrDefault();

            return response;

        }

    }
```

The problem is that when i resize an image smaller than 1024x1024, the FinalHeight and FinalWidth provides me with the dimensions 1024x1024.

I would expect the parameters to be 25x25 which is the size of my original image. How do i accomplish this?

Comment: How do you call the Resize method? Probably you are omiting maxHeight / maxWidth parameters and they are getting default values 1024x1024

Comment: @dlxeon the problem is that FinalHeight and FinalWidth is not reflecting the source image dimension. The source image is smaller than 1024x1024.

Comment: You are allowing to upscale image using ScaleMode.Both and it will upscale to 1024*1024 if you will pass size bigger than actual image size

Comment: Ah! Found you are using FitMode.Max. That's weird. Maybe it isn't compatible with ScaleMode.Both

Comment: @dlxeon you have a point though. let me try using DownscaleOnly.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, i had configured the instructions using ScaleMode.Both, and if you are using this in conjunction with the setting FitMode.Max it will still upscale the image to the configured height and width.